# Column numbers in 'awk' used with 'parallel' in a Makefile

Tags: awk, makefile, parallel-processing, gnu-make

Consider the following `Make` rule.

```
output.txt: input-*.txt
    parallel -j 16 'echo {} | awk "{print $$0}"' ::: $^
```

The problem is in specifying column numbers (or any dollar-variables) in awk. If the awk command is just in a Makefile (i.e., without being supplied to parallel) it works, but when used as an argument to parallel, it fails to work.

The following variation does not work either.

```
    parallel -j 16 'echo {} | awk "{print \$0}"' ::: $^
```

Could someone please help me fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make doesn't care about backslashes or quotes.  The only character (in a recipe) that make cares about is `$` and the only way to escape it is to double it: `$$`.  If using `$$0` doesn't work then the problem isn't with make, it's with your shell and/or parallel.

What you should do is run the command at the shell prompt and get it working there with whatever escaping is necessary, not worrying about make at all.

Once you have the rule properly escaped for the shell prompt, you can cut and paste it into your makefile recipe and replace all `$` characters with `$$` and it will work.

Looking at the parallel man page, it seems like the command you use cannot be an inline script which may be why your version doesn't work.  It apparently has to be an actual command.  Maybe if you used `/bin/sh -c "echo ..."` instead it would work?